# How to find specific values in database using arithmetic operators

Tags: prolog

I am having some problems with this base. I have no idea how to force answers other than "true" or "false" after giving question: `?- car(X,_,_,Y=<20000)`.

Which cars have been driven for less than 20000 km (the last number in list)?

I have tired:

```
Z=20000
car(X,_,_,Y) :-
Y=<Z
car(X,_,_,Y).
```

Also I have 2 questions:

1. Is it necessary to apply `use_module(library(clpfd))`?
2. Should I create some type of function or something?

```
car(opel, red, 2011, 10000).
car(bmw, black, 2010, 0).
car(bmw, green, 1999,20000).
car(bmw, black, 2015,10000).
car(fiat, white, 1988,100000).
car(fiat, red, 2000,200000).
car(nissan, black, 2014, 10000).
car(jaguar, silver, 2014, 10000).
car(opel, black, 2000, 150000).
car(opel, white, 2000, 15000).
```

I expect swi-prolog to show me all cars that have been driven for less than 20000 km. Of course line by line by pressing ; button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog is not a functional language. Thus, in your `car(X,_,_,Y=<20000)` query, `Y=<20000` is just a compound term with name `=<` and two arguments, `Y` and `2000`. This compound term is not evaluated as a function when used as an argument of the `car/4` predicate; you need to use it as a goal as follows. Try instead:

```
?- car(Brand, _, _, Mileage), Mileage =< 20000.
Brand = opel,
Mileage = 10000 ;
Brand = bmw,
Mileage = 0 ;
Brand = bmw,
Mileage = 20000 ;
Brand = bmw,
Mileage = 10000 ;
Brand = nissan,
Mileage = 10000 ;
Brand = jaguar,
Mileage = 10000 ;
Brand = opel,
Mileage = 15000.
```